# How to Split strings with fgets or fscanf in C?

Tags: c

I understand how to read in a text file and scan/print the entire file, but how can a line be split into several strings? Also, can variables be assigned to those strings to be called later?
My code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fPointer;
    fPointer = fopen("p1customer.txt", "r");
    char singleLine[150];
    int id;


    while (!feof(fPointer)){
        fscanf(fPointer, "%d", &id);
        printf("%d",id);

    }

    fclose(fPointer);
    return 0;   
}
```

Example Text File to be read:
99999 John Doe Basketball

Example Output:
John Doe has ID number 99999 and plays Basketball

I am attempting to split/tokenize those strings and assign them variables (IDnumber, Name, Sport) and print the output in a new file.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does your data look like? Is it all integers as your `fscanf` suggests?

Comment: You could read string from file using `fgets` (insted of using `feof` use return of `fgets` in loop condition) and then use [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/).

Comment: Essentially, I'm trying to read a line of text consisting of a set of integers and two separate sets of characters and rearrange them in a new file. So I thought there might be a way to actually split/parse each string, assign them to a variable, and rearrange them.

Comment: Read about why [`while (!feof(fp)) {}` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). An example of input and expected output would be helpful.

Comment: Note that, if end-of-file is reached with the call to `fscanf()`, the `printf()` is executed anyway. And the return value from the call to `fscanf()` is not checked; if input is not as expected, there is no code to handle the problem.

Comment: Please post (by editing the question) an example input file of a few lines, and the desired output for each line. I see you don't use `char singleLine[150];` so your intentions are unclear. Did you want code written for you?

Comment: "I understand how to read in a text file and scan/print the entire file" and `while (!feof(fPointer)){
        fscanf(fPointer, "%d", &id); ...` leaves doubts given that code is not testing the return value of `fscanf()`.  Better to use `while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fPointer)) { user_code_to_process_string_into_tokens(buf); }`

Comment: Chux I think this is helping in the right direction. Can fgets be followed by fputs to rearrrange newly assigned striings?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a library function `strtok(str,chrs)` function.
A sequence of calls of `strtok(str,chrs)` splits `str` into tokens, each delimited by a character from `chrs`.

The first call in a sequence is a non Null `str`.It finds the first token in `str` consisting of chars not int `chrs`;it terminates that by overwrtting the next characters of `str` by `\0` and return pointer to `token`. Each subsequent call,indicated by a `NULL` value of `str`,retuens a pointer to next such `token`, searching from just past the end of privious one.

Answer (score 0):

You should post an example of the input file so that you can help in more detail.
I've seen you've also entered a string, I guess you want to fill in with something but you did not specify that.
If you wanted to treat the file as a list of numbers, the sample of the code might be the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *infile;
    char buf[100];
    int len_file=0;

    if(!(infile = fopen("p1customer.txt", "r"))) { /*checks the correct opening of the file*/
        printf("Error in open p1customer.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while(fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),infile)!=NULL) /*check the lenght of the file (number of row) */
        len_file++;

    int id[len_file];
    int i=0;

    rewind(infile);

    while(fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),infile)!=NULL) {
        sscanf(buf,"%i",&id[i]);
        i++;
    }

    for(i=0;i<len_file;i++)
        printf("%i\n",id[i]);

    fclose(infile);

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to treat the file as an indefinite list of numbers on each row separated by a space, you can use the parsing of the string by using in the sscanf formatting `%31[^ ]`which has the task of reading the number until it encounters a space, also you can add a variable that is incremented for each char/number read.
Then you can refine the code by checking if there are any characters in the line using the `isalpha` function in the `ctype.h` library to see if there are any characters and then insert them into a string until you find the termination character `'\ 0'`.

The possibilities are infinite so it would useful have the input file, when you provided it, i'll update the answer.

Comment: Consider closing the file before re-opening it. -- better, just `rewind()` and not re-open.